# Is there a php function for generating associative array from indexed array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => '1 Fail'
    [1] => '2 Fail'
    [2] => '3 Pass'
    [3] => '4 Pass'
    [4] => '5 Pass'
)

Array
(
    ['1 Fail'] => '1 Fail'
    ['2 Fail'] => '2 Fail'
    ['3 Pass'] => '3 Pass'
    ['4 Pass'] => '4 Pass'
    ['5 Pass'] => '5 Pass'
)
```

Is there a php function to convert from array 1 to array 2

PS: I know this so i am looking for a built in function

```
foreach($result as $value)
{
    $assoc[$value] = $value;
}
```

Comment: You can swap keys and values, but I don't think there's a built-in function to copy values to their respective keys.

Comment: what's wrong with "this"? Why can't you browse array functions list yourself?

Comment: I won't think there is anything shorter than the four lines you already have.

Comment: nothings wrong but is there a way just for knowledge

Comment: This is a valid question., +1 PHP has built-ins for most any low-level array operation you could imagine. It's not at all unreasonable to expect there would be one for this, and to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming all your array values are unique:

```
$assoc = array_combine(array_values($arr), array_values($arr));
```

Comment: how different is ur approach from in terms of speed from @DaveRandom

Answer (score 1):

You could:

```
array_walk($array, function ($value, &$key) {
  $key = $value;
});
```

...but a more pertinent point is: *why do you need to do this?*

It seems like this is a very odd requirement, and whatever you need to do would be better done some other way...

Comment: how different is ur approach from in terms of speed from @codaddict

Comment: Unknown - probably depends very much on environment, PHP version and server configuration. It is unlikely to make any practical difference though, unless your array is ridiculously big. [Premature optimisation is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization), apparently (although personally, I suspect Micro$oft)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
$arr    = array(
'1 fail',
'2 fail',
'3 fail',
'4 fail',
);
print_r(array_combine($arr, $arr));



Array
(
    [1 fail] => 1 fail
    [2 fail] => 2 fail
    [3 fail] => 3 fail
    [4 fail] => 4 fail
)
```